# Identity involving vector cross and box products

Tags: vectors

How does one prove that

> $$[a \times b \,\,\, b \times c \,\,\, c \times a] = [a \,\,\, b \,\,\,c]^2?$$

I know that $[\,\cdot \,\,\, \cdot \,\,\, \cdot \,]$ is the box product. Should I assume that $a,b,c$ are the unit vectors $i, j, k$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Try writing $$[\vec{a}\times \vec{b} , \vec{b}\times \vec{c} , \vec{c}\times \vec{a}] = (\vec{a}\times \vec{b}).((\vec{b}\times \vec{c})\times(\vec{c}\times \vec{a})) $$
If you substitute $\vec{p}=(\vec{c}\times \vec{a})$,
$$RHS = (\vec{a}\times \vec{b}).((\vec{b}\times \vec{c})\times \vec{p})$$
$$=(\vec{a}\times \vec{b}).((\vec{b}.\vec{p})\vec{c} - (\vec{c}.\vec{p})\vec{b})$$
$$=(\vec{a}\times \vec{b}).([\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}]\vec{c} - \vec{0})$$
$$ = [\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}]^2$$

Comment: Perhaps you could be a little more specific? As written the hint really only writes out the definition of box product; neither of the mentioned properties can be invoked immediately.

Comment: @Travis I have edited my answer..

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee Cheers, the solution is very nice this way. (+1)